# Does the target matters on "telephone anchor" HTML

Tags: html, anchor

If I have some code like this:

```
<a href="tel:+17027613327" target="_blank">
    <font color="blue">
       <strong>702-761-3327</strong>
    </font>
</a>
```

The question is... does the target matters? can I put target='_blank' ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `tel:` is not a browser protocol, the `target` attribute doesn't have any meaning. You can safely get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

You've got a few options.

- `_self` will load into the current window.
- `_blank` loads a new window.
- `_parent` loads into the parent window, otherwise works the same way `_self` does
- `_top` loads into the ancestor of the clicked window who has no parent, meaning the top-level window. It also will work the same way `_self` does if there is no parent.

`_blank` sounds like the best if you don't want to change the user's current page, which it would seem like the desired effect when dialing a phone number.

Comment: OP knows what it does, they want to know if it has an effect when the href isn't a link.